# Is it possible to use expressions in if:true or if:false tag in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, html-template-directives

I have 8 parameters to render the elements conditionally, Is it possible to use expressions in if:true statement?

for example:

```
<template if:true={p1.data || p2.data || p3.data}>
   <!-- some elements -->
</template>
```

if not, do you have some suggestions?

p.s: use another parameter in .js `p = p1 || p2 || p3` usually cause a null pointer problem, because all parameters are retrieved asynchronously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, these kind of expressions are NOT supported in HTML template directives. Instead of using simple computed property, you should be using JS ***getters*** and you should be able to get around the null ref problem by placing relevant checks within the *getter* code. LWC developer guide states the following [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_directives).

> **if:true|false={expression}**
>
> Use this directive to conditionally render
> DOM elements in a template. The expression can be a JavaScript
> identifier (for example, person) or dot notation that accesses a
> property from an object (person.firstName). The engine doesn’t allow
> computed expressions (person[2].name['John']). ***To compute the value of
> expression, use a **getter** in the JavaScript class.***

Comment: thank you arut I'll check the document. Looks that I should've known *getter* earlier

Answer (score 3):

No LWC does not support expressions.

You can do the logic in `.js` and then set a getter property `boolMakeButtonVisible` as shown below.

Here methods `async1`, `async2`, `async3` are three async methods which demonstrates async updates to variables `boolasync1Done`, `boolasync2Done`, `boolasync3Done` respectively.

Something like this:

cmp :

```
<div if:true={boolMakeButtonVisible}>
    <lightning-button class="slds-m-left_x-small" variant="brand" label="Send Events" title="Primary action"
                      onclick={handleButtonClick}>Send Event
    </lightning-button>
</div>
```

---

```
boolasync1Done = false;
boolasync2Done = false;
boolasync3Done = false;

connectedCallback() {
    this.async1();
    this.async2();
    this.async3();
}

get boolMakeButtonVisible(){
    return this.boolasync1Done && this.boolasync2Done && this.boolasync3Done;
}

async1(){
    new Promise(resolve => {
        this.boolasync1Done = true;
    })
}

async2(){
    new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout( () => {
            this.boolasync2Done = true;
        }, 5000)
    })
}

async3(){
    new Promise(resolve => {
        this.boolasync3Done = true;
    })
}
```

Comment: The answer feels a bit over-complex; would this not work by having a getter based property like `get boolIsTrue() { return this.firstValue && this.secondValue && this.thirdValue && (the actual expression required based on first, second and third values); }`

Comment: Would getter still work if the value of `this.firstValue` is fetched after some few seconds than `this.secondValue && this.thirdValue` (As stated above all three values are coming in `Async`), also how will the getter again get triggered when `this.firstValue` changes from default to new value after few seconds.

Comment: I believe so. It should be triggered for each property being changed via a wire that is used within the method. If there's a problem with it not working then you might need to `@track` the getter (not sure).

Comment: Yeah then the above one seems a bit complex if it can be achieved via simple getter, thanks.

Comment: I suggest you give it a try for yourself then update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yep works, thanks, didn't know that. Updated answer.

Comment: I recommend updating the answer further to highlight that async1, 2 and 3 are to demonstrate async updates only and that they don't actually form part of the formal solution which is to use a getter-based property. I would also change the name of `checkIfAllThreeAreDone` since this doesn't make logical sense in the template usage.

Comment: You should probably just use Promise.all() and set one variable.

Answer (score 2):

`if:true` and `if:false` are going to be deprecated. Its successor - `lwc:if` - also does not support expressions according to the [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_if_else.htm&release=242&type=5):

> Complex expressions like !condition or object?.property?.condition
> aren’t supported. To evaluate complex expressions, use a getter in
> your JavaScript class.

Comment: what if we want to render if the flag is false? i am trying to set it `lwc:if={!condition}` OR `lwc:if={condition == false}` but it does not work

Comment: You will have to create yet another getter function in JavaScript.

Comment: Then you leave `lwc:if` empty and use `lwc:else`.
`
<template>
  <template lwc:if={condition}><!--nothing--> </template>
  <template lwc:else> Statement2 </template>
</template>
`